# How can I restore my Azure account which is compromised

Tags: azure

I have shared my Azure subscription ID and Tenant ID publicly by mistake and can't take it back. Is there any chance of my Azure account to be compromised? If yes, then what are the solutions?

Comment: Azure AD tenant ids at least are definitely public and easy to find if you know the domain someone is using. Subscription ids themselves are also basically just identifiers. The only real attack I could see happening is some kind of social engineering to Azure support using the ids and claiming to be the admin. But Azure support could easily contact you and verify the claim though. I think the risk is quite small.

Comment: **Thank you so much for your valuable answer**